# Error making new contract: Type contract is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to update this code to 0.6.6 to use alongside some other contracts and I got everything except this. I don't know what else to try to get it to work.

Error:

```
contracts/TimeLockedWalletFactory.sol:22:19: TypeError: Type contract TimeLockedWallet is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable. wallet = new TimeLockedWallet(addy, _owner, _unlockDate); ^---------------------------------------------^
```

Here's the TimeLockedWalletFactory contract that the error comes from:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
```

import "./TimeLockedWallet.sol";

contract TimeLockedWalletFactory {

```
mapping(address => address[]) wallets;

function getWallets(address _user) 
    public
    view
    returns(address[])
{
    return wallets[_user];
}

function newTimeLockedWallet(address _owner, uint256 _unlockDate)
    payable
    public
    returns(address wallet)
{
    // Create new wallet.
    wallet = new TimeLockedWallet(msg.sender, _owner, _unlockDate);
    
    // Add wallet to sender's wallets.
    wallets[msg.sender].push(wallet);

    // If owner is the same as sender then add wallet to sender's wallets too.
    if(msg.sender != _owner){
        wallets[_owner].push(wallet);
    }

    // Send ether from this transaction to the created contract.
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);

    // Emit event.
    Created(wallet, msg.sender, _owner, now, _unlockDate, msg.value);
}

// Prevents accidental sending of ether to the factory
function () public {
    revert();
}

event Created(address wallet, address from, address to, uint256 createdAt, uint256 unlockDate, uint256 amount);
```

}

Here's the TimeLockedWallet code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
```

import "./ERC20.sol";

contract TimeLockedWallet {

```
address public creator;
address public owner;
uint256 public unlockDate;
uint256 public createdAt;

modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function TimeLockedWallet(
    address _creator,
    address _owner,
    uint256 _unlockDate
) public {
    creator = _creator;
    owner = _owner;
    unlockDate = _unlockDate;
    createdAt = now;
}

// keep all the ether sent to this address
function() payable public { 
    Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

// callable by owner only, after specified time
function withdraw() onlyOwner public {
   require(now >= unlockDate);
   //now send all the balance
   msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
   Withdrew(msg.sender, this.balance);
}

// callable by owner only, after specified time, only for Tokens implementing ERC20
function withdrawTokens(address _tokenContract) onlyOwner public {
   require(now >= unlockDate);
   ERC20 token = ERC20(_tokenContract);
   //now send all the token balance
   uint256 tokenBalance = token.balanceOf(this);
   token.transfer(owner, tokenBalance);
   WithdrewTokens(_tokenContract, msg.sender, tokenBalance);
}

function info() public view returns(address, address, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    return (creator, owner, unlockDate, createdAt, this.balance);
}

event Received(address from, uint256 amount);
event Withdrew(address to, uint256 amount);
event WithdrewTokens(address tokenContract, address to, uint256 amount);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have change the type of wallet from 'address' to 'TimeLockedWallet'.

```
function newTimeLockedWallet(address _owner, uint256 _unlockDate)
    payable
    public
    returns(TimeLockedWallet wallet)
{
    // Create new wallet.
    wallet = new TimeLockedWallet(msg.sender, _owner, _unlockDate);
    
    // Add wallet to sender's wallets.
    wallets[msg.sender].push(address(wallet));

    // If owner is the same as sender then add wallet to sender's wallets too.
    if(msg.sender != _owner){
        wallets[_owner].push(address(wallet));
    }

    // Send ether from this transaction to the created contract.
    payable(wallet).transfer(msg.value);

    // Emit event.
    Created(address(wallet), msg.sender, _owner, now, _unlockDate, msg.value);
}
```

Find the full code here : https://github.com/KeerthanaRamalingam/Stackoverflow/blob/main/Changeversionto0.6.6.sol

Comment: You can mark the answer is right. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. Your `wallet` memory variable is defined as an `address`, and in your code you're trying to set it to a `TimeLockedWallet` contract instance. Contract instances are not implicitly convertible to an `address` type.

You need to either explicitly define the conversion, as in:

```
wallet = address(new TimeLockedWallet(msg.sender, _owner, _unlockDate));
```

Or more preferably, you could change `wallet`'s definition to be of type `TimeLockedWallet` as follows:

```
function newTimeLockedWallet(address _owner, uint256 _unlockDate)
    payable
    public
    returns(TimeLockedWallet memory wallet)
{
...
}

event Created(TimeLockedWallet memory wallet, address from, address to, uint256 createdAt, uint256 unlockDate, uint256 amount);
```